# Laravel - Controller - Dynamic Menu - All Pages

Tags: laravel, menu, controller

I'm making a website where the menu is manageable by the administrator, my question is how to mount that select to display on all pages.

At first I was doing the query of the menus in all actions of the controller, but I would like to optimize this, just do not know how.

My Controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Categorias;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller {

    public $template = 'default';

    // Retorna Navegação
    public function retornaNavegacao(){

        $sql = Categorias::where([
                ['exibir', '=', 1], ['publicado', '=', 1]
            ])
            ->get();

        return $sql;
    }

    // Página 'Categorias'
    public function categoria(){

        return view('frontend.'.$this->template.'.categorias.index', 
            array(
                'mainMenu' => $this->retornaNavegacao(),
            )
        );

    }

    // Página 'Produtos'
    public function produto(){

        return view('frontend.'.$this->template.'.produtos.index', 
            array(
                'mainMenu' => $this->retornaNavegacao(),
            )
        );

    }

    // Página 'Contato'
    public function contato(){

        return view('frontend.'.$this->template.'.contato.index', 
            array(
                'mainMenu' => $this->retornaNavegacao(),
            )
        );

    }

}
```

The function retornaNavegacao() only queries the database and returns all registered menus (There is a relationship to search for all subcategories).

However I have to repeat the menu code in all the actions of the controller, I think it might have a smarter way of not having to repeat this code in all actions.

Comment: use view-composer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `AppServiceProvider` class edit `boot` method

```
public function boot()
{
    $categories = Categorias::where([
            ['exibir', '=', 1],
            ['publicado', '=', 1]
        ])
        ->get();

    View::composer('*', function ($view) use ($categories) {
        $view->with(['mainMenu' => $categories]);
    });
}
```

Also you can use all power of laravel

```
public function boot()
{
    $mainMenu = Categorias::whereWxibir(1)
        ->wherePublicado(1)
        ->get();

    View::composer('*', function ($view) use ($mainMenu) {
        $view->with(compact('mainMenu'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can share a variable in all of your views from app service provider's boot method.

```
public function boot()
{

    $mainMenu = $this->retornaNavegacao(),

     view()->share(compact('mainMenu'));
}
```

If you want to share the variable in just some specific views you can make your own [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers).